# Log viewer to format Java object toString()'s into nested more readable form

Tags: java, logging

At our workplace we use a rather standard Java toString() formatting which looks something like this:

```
entity=MyClass1[param1=value,param2=<null>,param3=1234,param4=MyOtherClass[param1=otherValue1,param2=otherValue2]]
```

With some of our domain object graphs being quite large, a single toString() can be thousands of characters long, resulting in some very unreadable log files.

It would be good to selectively "expand" a toString(), either with a macro, a special log viewer, vim scripts, something else??, so that such a log line would expand to look more like this:

```
entity=MyClass1[
    param1=value,
    param2=<null>,
    param3=1234,
    param4=MyOtherClass[
        param1=otherValue1,
        param2=otherValue2
    ]
]
```

Does anyone have any neat solutions for this?

Comment: If it is just for post processing on demand, you could use Regex

Comment: Is that `toString` generated by Eclipse or other IDE? Or does it come from commons-lang?

Comment: The toString() most of us use is the one generated from Intellij.  I think the example above matches the exact format.

Comment: I should probably add that we would prefer the original logged toString() to all be on one line.  So that we can use monit to pattern match on certain log lines.  It would be nice to selectively "expand" or "format" a selected line on demand in some tool.